# How do you use mathematical symbols on this website?

Tags: support, mathjax

For example, how do I the symbol f(x) and make it appear as mathematical appearing instead of just appear as text.

I know I am going to get downvotes for this, but I couldn't find any help files regarding this. Thanks to anyone who answers!

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll check it out right now

Comment: Do a Google search for "latex", and no I am not trolling you.

Comment: `f(x)` gives f(x). `$f(x)$` gives $f(x)$. `$$f(x)$$` gives $$f(x).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) mentions the system used. If you want f(x) to look like $f(x)$. Then type \$ f(x) \$.